# Media Player Raw Directory in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When we create media player in android then why it is mandatory to save media in raw folder? Can I not save in any other folder?

Comment: read this doc : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no it is not mandatory.you can also save in Assets folder

Comment: check this link you see image up-vote or down-vote.if any answer is helping you then click up-vote button